# Why the past perfect is used in the sentence and is it correct?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

The sentence:

> Remove products that are part of a bundle from the cart when the
> bundle has been added to the cart.

Why using the past perfect here **"when the bundle has been added to the cart"**

If the above sentence is not grammatically correct, how to correct it?

Please help and thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Past perfect isn't used.  The present perfect in the passive voice  is used "has been added"

The writer uses a passive voice form "be added".  This is because the topic and grammatical subject "the bundle" is the object of the verb "add".

The writer uses the present perfect "has been added", because you should remove items that are part of bundle only when you have finished adding the bundle, not while you are adding the bundle.